# split a string based on a typical condition in java?

Tags: java, regex

My input string is as follows :

```
String sample1 = "productName/@languageCode";
String sample1="brandNameInformation/languageSpecificBrandName/@languageCode";
```

I want to split it only when there is occurence of "/" and not when "/@"

how can i do it?
can anyone help?

Comment: `String[] parts = sample1.split("/[^@]");`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and search for "lookahead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample1 = "productName/@languageCode";
        String sample2 ="brandNameInformation/languageSpecificBrandName/@languageCode";

        String regex = "/(?!@)";

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sample1.split(regex)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sample2.split(regex)));
    }
}
```

output:

```
[productName/@languageCode]
[brandNameInformation, languageSpecificBrandName/@languageCode]
```